# How to get MMS/SMS message info in app?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, sms, mms

I want to get the MMS/SMS message info in my app when the server pushes one MMS/SMS message. But I cannot find any API to get this info; I just can send MMS/SMS using the `MFMessageComposeViewController` class.

How can obtain this information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no public API to enable you to read MMS/SMS messages.

Answer (score 1):

By adding an URL scheme to your app, you can get information (encoded in an URL inside the SMS) from an SMS into your app indirectly: the user needs to open the SMS and tap the link.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible yet with any official Apple API's